# why when using while the var is not updated and print after start var only?

Tags: c++

I wanna make a code to sync clock now and clock targeted, but the code print the same clock as first start when using while.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    time_t now = time(0);
    tm *ltm = localtime(&now);
        do{ 
        if(ltm->tm_sec > 60){
          cout << "ok : " << ltm->tm_sec << endl;
          break;
        } else {
          cout << "ok : " << ltm->tm_sec << endl;
          continue;
        }
    }while (ltm->tm_sec <= 60);
}
```

I expect it will print the new clock now but it print as same as when start the code time.

Comment: You never update `now` to the current now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update `now` & `ltm` variable with current time inside `do-while` loop.

You may change your code as below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    time_t now = time(0);
    tm *ltm;
    do
    {
           now = time(0);
           ltm = localtime(&now);
           if(ltm->tm_sec > 60)
           {
               cout << "ok : " << ltm->tm_sec << endl;
               break;
           }
           else
           {
                 cout << "ok : " << ltm->tm_sec << endl;
                 continue;
           }
      }while (ltm->tm_sec <= 60);
  return 0;
  }
```

I hope it works!

Comment: Welcome @hmm15.